# convert to 24 hour format then timestamp

Tags: php, datetime

My datetime formatting is not working. I need to convert a `12 hour format` time to `24 hour format` after that the time's timestamp is required. so my code is

```
$to =  DateTime::createFromFormat('h:i A','1:00 AM');
echo $to->format('d M y H:i').'<br/>'; 
echo $to->getTimestamp();
```

My 2nd line code's desired result is 24 hour format of  `28 Sep 15 1:00 AM` and then timestamp of this datetime. Whats wrong in my code?

**My Problem is the timestamp of `28 Sep 15 1:00 AM` is smaller than the timestamp of `28 Sep 15 8:00 PM`. But WHY?**

Comment: Why do you need to convert 1:00 AM to 1:00 PM? The code above works just fine, and spits out 1:00 AM as expected. Try with an input time in PM and you'll see that it works.

Comment: I dont need to convert 1:00 AM to 1:00 PM. I need 24 hour format of `1:00 AM`

Comment: The 24h format of 1:00 AM is 01:00. If that's what you wanted your code was already fine from the start.

Comment: Problem between chair and keyboard?

Comment: problem is  timestamp of `28 Sep 15 1:00 AM` is smaller than `28 Sep 15 8:00 PM` WHY??

Comment: 1:00 AM is 01:00 in 24h format and 8:00 PM is 20:00 in 24h format, so within the same calendar day the 8 PM timestamp will always be greater than the 1 AM.

Comment: Maybe you want to compare with 8:00 PM from the previous day (27 Sep 15)?

Comment: No I need to compare same day's timestamp of `28 Sep 15 1:00 AM` and `28 Sep 15 8:00 PM`. however found the problem. The issue is both time are not same day

Answer (score 2):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time

> ... defined as the number of seconds that have elapsed since 00:00:00
>   Thursday, 1 January 1970

--

> My Problem is the timestamp of 28 Sep 15 1:00 AM is smaller than the
>   timestamp of 28 Sep 15 8:00 PM. But WHY?

Being timestamp "the number of seconds that have elapsed since 00:00:00 Thursday, 1 January 1970" obviously 28 Sep 15 1:00 AM will always be smaller than 28 Sep 15 8:00 PM the same way that 28 Sep 15 00:00 *AM* will always be smaller than 28 Sep 15 00:00 *PM*

Answer (score 0):

Add this line after the first one:

```
$to->modify('+12 hours');
```

EDIT:
I'm not really getting what you need exactly, so here you have some samples:

```
$am = DateTime::createFromFormat('h:i A','1:00 AM');
echo $am->format('d M y H:i');   // prints '28 Sep 15 01:00'
echo $am->format('d M y h:i A'); // prints '28 Sep 15 01:00 AM'

$pm = DateTime::createFromFormat('h:i A','8:00 PM');
echo $pm->format('d M y H:i');   // prints '28 Sep 15 20:00'
echo $pm->format('d M y h:i A'); // prints '28 Sep 15 08:00 PM'
```

Code sample here: https://3v4l.org/PvAGm

Comment: hello i need to convert `1:00 AM` not `1:00 PM`

Comment: @RejoanulAlam - If the desired result is `13:00`, then it needs to be `1:00 PM`.... or do you mean you need to convert from one timezone to another?

Comment: @RejoanulAlam I've edited my answer. Maybe what you want is increment the time from 1AM to 1PM then?

Comment: I have edited my requirement and made it more clear. Please see now